# Youtube `unique` view metric for number of unique views on the video

Tags: youtube, youtube-analytics

Is there a way to get a sense of the number of unique views of your channel on Youtube. I understand that the unique views as a metric was deprecated as of September 2016 but wanted to be see if there are alternate ways of getting a sense